# \cref : "Argument of \textsf has an extra }."

Tags: hyperref, cleveref, amsthm

So I have this bit of code

```
\begin{ex}
    The prototype for an abelian category is $\Mod_R$, in fact every abelian category is equivalent to a full subcategory of $\Mod_R$ as we will see in \cref{FMET}.
\end{ex}
```

Which I have defined here

```
\begin{theo}\label{FMET}
    Any additive category is equivalent to a full subcategory of $\Mod_R$.
\end{theo}
```

I first include this

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, %colorise les liens
linkcolor=black,
urlcolor=black,
citecolor=black,
breaklinks=true, %permet le retour à la ligne dans les liens trop longs
pdftitle={}, pdfauthor={}, pdfsubject={}
}
```

And only then do I introduce

```
\newtheorem{theo}{\textsf{Theorem}}[subsection]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theo]{\textsf{Lemma}}
\newtheorem{cor}[theo]{\textsf{Corollary}}
\newtheorem{prop}[theo]{\textsf{Proposition}}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{rk}{\textsf{Remark}}
\newtheorem*{rks}{\textsf{Remarks}}
\newtheorem{defi}[theo]{\textsf{Definition}}
\newtheorem{defis}[theo]{\textsf{Definitions}}
\newtheorem*{nota}{\textsf{Notation}}
\newtheorem*{notas}{\textsf{Notations}}
\newtheorem{ex}[theo]{\textsf{Example}}
\newtheorem{exs}[theo]{\textsf{Examples}}
\newtheorem{ctrex}[theo]{\textsf{Counter-example}}
```

However I get the error that you can read in the title at the first line that I sent you. Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and please always try to show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) instead of some code snippets. Otherwise we need to guess how to combine and extend them to make the problem reproducible and help you.

Comment: @Mico I'm using `amsthm` so tried adding `ntheorem` and it doesn't produce any PDF (whether it's added before or after `amsthm`) but then if I only use `ntheorem`it says that the environment `proof` are not defined and a shitload of other errors.

Comment: @Mico `\DeclareMathOperator{\Mod}{\textbf{Mod}}` in the same .sty document as all the packages an the `\newtheorem`'s

Comment: That's how it was when I created my post, only `amsthm` but no `ntheorem`

Comment: Because you mentionned it so I tried it

Comment: make a small but complete example that shows the error and can be used for a test.

Comment: I litterally said "I'm using `amsthm`"

Comment: So all the `\newtheorem` are only to be used with `ntheorem`? Do you suggest that I switch to `ntheorem`?

Comment: @Mico No problem, thanks for trying

Comment: @UlrikeFischer 
`\begin{document}

    \begin{theo}\label{test}
        A test
    \end{theo}

    The \cref{test}

\end{document}`

Produces the error "Argument of \textsf has an extra }." on the last line, the one with \cref{test} is it what you asked?

Comment: I've edited your posting to (a) delete the `ntheorem` tag and (b) add the `amsthm` tag.

Comment: (1) Delete the .aux file. (2) Put an extra set of braces around `\textsf{whatever}` (i.e. use `{\textsf{whatever}}`). (3) Don't ask me why this makes the error go away!

Comment: A complete example should start with \documentclass and end with \end{document}. If I copy & paste it and then compile it should show the error. You can edit your question and put the example there.

Comment: @IanThompson Thanks a lot! Only needed to rebrace the \textsf, I've seen it solve my problems before, should've thought of it

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't have formatting instructions in the theorem label definition.

The best would be to define a proper theorem style, but in this simple case you can get away with the following trick.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, %colorise les liens
linkcolor=black,
urlcolor=black,
citecolor=black,
breaklinks=true, %permet le retour à la ligne dans les liens trop longs
pdftitle={}, pdfauthor={}, pdfsubject={}
}

\makeatletter
\thm@headfont={\bfseries\sffamily}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}[subsection]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theo]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}[theo]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{prop}[theo]{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{rk}{Remark}
\newtheorem*{rks}{Remarks}
\newtheorem{defi}[theo]{Definition}
\newtheorem{defis}[theo]{Definitions}
\newtheorem*{nota}{Notation}
\newtheorem*{notas}{Notations}
\newtheorem{ex}[theo]{Example}
\newtheorem{exs}[theo]{Examples}
\newtheorem{ctrex}[theo]{Counter-example}

\newcommand{\Mod}{\mathbf{Mod}}% <-- NOT \DeclareMathOperator

\begin{document}

\section{Test}
\subsection{Test}

\begin{theo}\label{FMET}
 Any additive category is equivalent to a full subcategory of $\Mod_R$.
\end{theo}

\Cref{FMET}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Side notes.

Your `\Mod` is not a math operator, but a standard ordinary atom. Using `\textbf` is wrong, because you'd get italic inside a theorem statement.